# Huge JSON object handling in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have to handle a huge JSON object (several gigabytes) in a nodejs project.
In java there is a nice project called MapDB that helps storing huge maps in a file and makes it possible to access it as if it were a normal map but still avoid to load the whole file in memory.

Is there any equivalent project for nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need streaming JSON parsing library like [BFJ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj) or [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream).

From BFJ documentation:

> **Why would I want those?**
>
> If you need to parse huge JSON strings or
> stringify huge JavaScript data sets, it monopolises the event loop and
> can lead to out-of-memory exceptions. BFJ implements asynchronous
> functions and uses pre-allocated fixed-length arrays to try and
> alleviate those issues.

Comment: I know those libraries. The point is that at the end of the show they are loading the whole object in memory; and this is not my use case because of the thousands of nested objects I am going to use only a small percentage

Comment: They specifically allow you to stream your data, and not have everything in memory